# show that the number can also be written in an other way

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that,if a number is written $6k+5,$ for a $k$,then it is also written $3l+2$,for a $l$.Prove that the reverse does not apply.
How can I do this?I tried to apply the euclidean algorithm,but I couldn't show what I have to..

Comment: **Hint**: $6k= 3\cdot(2k)$

Comment: Could you at least prove that the reverse is not true? If not, do you have an idea of how you might do that?

Comment: Another suggestion: Try some examples.  The claim is about numbers that can be written as $6k+5$.  What are some examples of such numbers?  List some, then pick one and see if you can write it as $3l+2$.  Then try another.  See if you notice a pattern.

Comment: $6k+5$ can be written as $3(2k+1)+2$,so $l$ must be equal to $2k+1$..right?But couldn't I prove it,using identities of divisibility?

Comment: You just did prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just say:$$6k+5=3l+2$$so: $$l=\frac{6k+3}{3}$$ $$k=\frac{3l-3}{6}$$The second equation gives an integer $l$ for all $k$;  the third does ***not*** give integer $k$ for all $l$.